# How to fix dpkg error [2]?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Every time I try to install or remove a package, I get this error. I thought maybe it was the hard disk, but a disk check gave me a clean bill of health.

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.16.0-31': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

I tried the solution of removing the listing for this file from the dpkg status file, but to no avail. I tried purging the package but no use. I'm stuck at this point as nothing I can find on Google helps.

#### Update:

This is now what the error says:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

After trying: https://askubuntu.com/a/603305/1992

#### Update2:

Seems the drive has bad sectors, but the reallocated sector count is 0. The drive is relatively old, however, so I expect some issues. I won't be able to replace it immediately, and until then I would still like to be able to keep the system up to date (especially for security reasons).

I noted that there was an issue with coping some md5 checksums related to the package mentioned in the error, but I don't know what to do with those, such as if clearing them would allow dpkg to continue.

Comment: How would you remove the offending package?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/603429/1992

Comment: check this website , it may help.
https://appuals.com/fix-could-not-open-file-var-lib-dpkg-status/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271541) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232143&p=10010092#post10010092).

What puzzles me is that I tried this twice before and it didn't work. It probably worked this time because I used a script I found on launchpad answers that backed up and restored what it could... I don't know. Either way, here is the fix:

- `pkexec gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status`
- Search for the offending package by name and remove its entry.
- Save the file and exit gedit.
- run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- run `sudo apt-get -f install` just in case.
- Continue on if there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

**if u still have the error after run** 
`sudo dpkg --configure -a` #remove the file where u have the error after going to the location
`cd location`
`rm -rf file-name`[for eg. 0004]   #then try again
`sudo apt-get -f install`

it will work