# Whatever the command I give

Tags: 14.04, apt, 64-bit

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and **amd64** bit processor

Whatever the command I give(Except `sudo apt-get autoclean`), I'm getting the below response :-

```
dpkg: error processing package libuuid1:amd64 (--configure):
 package libuuid1:amd64 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6 cannot be configured because libuuid1:i386 is at a different version (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

On giving this command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get the below error :-

```
dpkg: error processing package libuuid1:amd64 (--configure):
 package libuuid1:amd64 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6 cannot be configured because libuuid1:i386 is at a different version (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4)
dpkg: error processing package libuuid1:i386 (--configure):
 package libuuid1:i386 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4 cannot be configured because libuuid1:amd64 is at a different version (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libuuid1:amd64
 libuuid1:i386
```

Note:I do not remember what all I have UN-installed so far from my system,so I do not have any thought what's going on.

Please help me out, Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to askubuntu. If you can install synaptics and fix broken packages

Comment: I'm not able to install any, even if I try to install `sudo apt-get install synaptic`  then it throws the same error

`Fetched 3,299 kB in 22s (147 kB/s)                                             
dpkg: error processing package libuuid1:amd64 (--configure):
 package libuuid1:amd64 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6 cannot be configured because libuuid1:i386 is at a different version (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libuuid1:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: here is a fix that may work http://askubuntu.com/questions/603295/how-to-fix-dpkg-error-2

Answer (score 0):

What dpkg wants is for both packages to have the same version. In principle it's the same package, but one is for i386 (32-bit) while the other is amd64 (64-bit). So you have two options:

1. `sudo apt-get install libuuid1:i386`, in the hopes that this will install version 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6 and resolve the conflict.
2. `sudo apt-get remove libuuid1:i386`, completely removing that package and leaving only libuuid1:amd64. This may also remove other packages which may or may not be needed, but I can't tell based on the information you gave.

Comment: I have tried this so many time but no use
`E: Unable to locate package libuuid1` this what I got

Comment: Can you please run `dpkg --list "*libuuid*"` and paste the output somewhere? maybe paste.ubuntu.com. Post the link here for us to see.

Comment: http://164.164.34.73/files/libuuid_output.txt

Answer (score 0):

So if you run for instance `ls` you get this error? Seems odd?

Logging for apt is located in `/var/log/apt/`, you can read the .gz logs with `zcat` or `zmore`.

I got this update on august 5th

```
Preparing to unpack .../libuuid1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libuuid1:i386 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) ...
Unpacking libuuid1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6) over (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libuuid1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libuuid1:i386 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6) over (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) ...
Setting up libuuid1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6) ...
Setting up libuuid1:i386 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6) ...
```

I got version 20.4 in February:

```
De-configuring libuuid1:i386 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.3) ...
Unpacking libuuid1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) over (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libuuid1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libuuid1:i386 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) over (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libblkid1_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libblkid1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) over (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.3) ...
Setting up libuuid1:amd64 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) ...
Setting up libuuid1:i386 (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4) ..
```

Did you anywhere in the meantime disable/block i386 updates for instance?

Do any of you apt-sources have `arch=` [defined](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)? example:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main universe
deb [arch=armel,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports quantal main universe
```

(check with [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647454/how-to-get-a-list-of-repositories-apt-get-is-checking) `grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` )

Perhaps [revert the 64bit-version to previous version](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1033841&p=8695736#post8695736) and try again whatever it is you needed to do?

Possibly you may have to [pin that previous version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) to prevent the same error again.

Comment: 1. No I have not disable/block i386 updates
2. After executing this command `grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`
`grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list: No such file or directory`

Comment: So you only get the error? No other output? That probaly means you have no sources at all anymore? Is there still a file "/etc/apt/sources.list.save? What's the output of `grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list* /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` ?

Comment: Output:
http://164.164.34.73/files/output.txt

Comment: Weird, it's impossible that that would be the output of that grep-command. Even if the caret were missing, the word "deb" is not inthere. Given the fact you're seeing an 164.x.x.x address (which seems to be linked to STPI-BANGALORE) it seems like a custom install, and you may want to take it up with those server-admins?

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about point.