# Error while installing Software Center

Tags: gnome, software-installation, software-center, dependencies, error-handling

When I try to install Software Center it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: gnome-settings-daemon (< 3.19.92) but 3.18.2-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
                             Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.18.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 perl-base : Breaks: debconf (< 1.5.61) but 1.5.58ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Breaks: debconf:i386 (< 1.5.61)
 software-center : Depends: python-apt (>= 0.8.3ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-oneconf (>= 0.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            oneconf (< 0.3) but 0.3.9 is to be installed
                   Recommends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, but your packages don't match up with any supported release of Ubuntu, meaning you're not using Ubuntu, or have very non-standard sources added (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gsettings-desktop-schemas&searchon=names https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-apt)

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/software-center makes it look like you have 16.04 installed, but it's better if we are told than having to guess.  The obvious fix is `sudo apt -f install` but your unusual sources are I suspect  your issue.

Comment: my operating system is 16.04

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix packages, and install unmet dependencies, you can download the Ubuntu Software Install from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/software-center. Before you downlaod this, try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This is cited from [How to fix dpkg error [2]?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603295/how-to-fix-dpkg-error-2).
There may be a better explanation on there for you. I hope this helps.

Comment: For those trying to copy-paste the command is `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (space after --configure)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @raghav710

Comment: I updated it, so, again, thanks for pointing it out